# Angular moment translation for AM/PM in german

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

My site is in german and i use [moment](http://momentjs.com/) and [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) for transaltion. Everything working fine except AM/PM. My code

```
<time>{{ messagedata.created*1000| amDateFormat: 'D, MMM YYYY, h:mm:ss A' }}</time>
```

Result: `16, Febr. 2017, 5:30:00 AM` 
Wanted Result: `16, Febr. 2017, 5:30:00 Uhr`

Configuration

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location, amMoment, moment) {
amMoment.changeLocale(LANGCODE);
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    relativeTime : {
        m:  "1 Minute",
        h:  "an Hour",
        d:  "1 Day",
        M:  "1 Month",
        y:  "1 Year",
    }
});
moment.updateLocale('de', {
    relativeTime : {
        m:  "1 Minute",
        d:  "1 Tag",
        M:  "1 Monat",
        y:  "1 Jahr",
    }
});
```

});

So, I want to change AM/PM in german,Is it possible? How?

Comment: have you tried including the german locale?

Comment: yes . it is included and working correctly. `february` is changed but `am/pm` not changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

German time doesnt work/go with AM/PM. German time is in 24h format. Also the day date ends with an `.` instead of an `,`. Finally the correct output would be: `16. Febr. 2017, 17:30:00 Uhr`. That's what we (germans) would expect as a correct date format :)

```
<time>{{ messagedata.created*1000| amDateFormat: 'D. MMM YYYY, HH:mm:ss' }} Uhr</time>
```

---

```
H, HH       24 hour time
h, or hh    12 hour time (use in conjunction with a or A)
```

> 24-hour time notation is used officially and for purposes that require
>   precision like announcements in the media. In colloquial speech, a
>   12-hour clock is used.

**Note** colloquial speech != technical correct output.

---

If you still wand to use the `A` placeholder you could create an own `meridiem` replacement like:

```
// From 2.8.1 to 2.11.2
moment.locale('de', {
    meridiem : function () {
        return 'Uhr';
    }
});
```

In that way the following format should work for you:

```
<time>{{ messagedata.created*1000| amDateFormat: 'D. MMM YYYY, HH:mm:ss A' }}</time>
```

---

An other solution could be handled with `angular-translate`. Just create the correct `meridiem` translation inside your translation files. This solution would look like:

```
<time>
    {{ messagedata.created*1000| amDateFormat: 'D. MMM YYYY, HH:mm:ss' }}
    <span translate="meridiem"></span>
</time>
```

Comment: `Uhr` is hard coded here. What will happen if my site has 2-3 more different languages?

Comment: @SRana updated, wasnt finished with the answer. :). Btw. are you using `angular-translate`?

Comment: @lin Yes , I m using `angular-translate`

Comment: Nice discussion on 24 hour time versus 12 hour time and when they are used in Germany

Comment: `meridiem ` worked for me.. But don't know which answer i need to accept. One is correct and one is descriptive. Thank you both of you @lin @PerttuHaliseva

Comment: @SRana the force is with you :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `meridiem` customization: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/am-pm/

Just add another property for `de`, which should be a function. Function can always return static translation 'Uhr' so you won't be needing parameters `hour, minute, isLowercase` from function signature:

```
meridiem : function () {
    return 'Uhr';
}
```